# Почему mousemove срабатывает при mousedown?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Вот кусок кода, который выводит в консоль "111" при простом клике. Куда смотреть?

```
$(document).on("mousemove touchmove", function() {
var pageX = event.pageX || event.touches[0].pageX,
moveLeft = startX - pageX;

mouseMoved = true;

console.log(111);

sliderWrapper.css({
"left": sliderWrapperLeft - moveLeft
});

});
```

Comment: а если тач убрать?

Comment: @teran то же самое

Comment: Причем вроде скрипт работал, я обновил страницу и столкнулся с проблемой.

Comment: @Александр Запустил у себя, при движении работает, при клике нет. Может у Вас ещё какие-либо функции есть? Дополните, пожалуйста, код таким образом, чтобы можно было воспроизвести Вашу ошибку.

Comment: @Denis640Kb Запустил на jsfiddle этот код, проблема повторяется. Chrome, версия 80.0.3987.122

Comment: @Александр Дайте ссылку на Ваш код на jsfiddle.

Comment: @Denis640Kb [ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/5yo9q4u0/)

Comment: тогда не двигайте мышью, когда кликаете :D

Comment: @Александр Проверил Ваш код по ссылке. У Вас так же не срабатывает код при клике. Только при передвижении мыши. Подскажите, какая у Вас вообще задача стоит? Может посоветуем, как лучше реализовать. В текущем варианте той ошибки, которую Вы описываете в вопросе нет. Может Вы действительно двигаете мышкой при клике?

Comment: @Denis640Kb мышь, тачпад, кнопки на тачпаде. В firefox проблемы нет.

Comment: @Александр Смотрите, я в `chrome` запускаю Ваш код. Если просто кликаю мышкой или тачпадом(нажимая на тачпад), то `111` не выводится. Если происходит любое смещение мышки во время клика или без, то в консоль выводится соответствующая информация.

Comment: @Denis640Kb пришлось дописать: `mouseMoved = moveLeft != 0 ? true : false;`